# Prevent Duplicity (through form) in MeteorJS collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

I am collecting data through a form & saving it to meteor collection using the class of inputs(Work fine). Now i want to prevent duplicate entry of "Email" & "Category" combination(A user cannot apply for a category from same email twice). Please help.!!
Also tell me how to generate thank you alert with name filled in form

```
         /*Meteor JS File*/

Info = new Meteor.Collection("info");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.add_info.events({
   'submit form':function(){
   Info.insert({
    category:$('.the_item11').val(),
    name:$('.the_item1').val(),
    mobile:$('.the_item2').val(),
    Mail:$('.the_item3').val(),
    createdAt: new Date(),
        });

    if ($.trim($("#uname").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#umobile").val()) === ""){
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        return false;                                  }            

    alert("Thank You For Registering")      
                }
           });          
         }


                           /*HTML form*/
<head>
  <title>yahaviform</title>

</head>

<body>
<img src="EDMcrowd.jpg" name="CA_5" id="CA_5"/>
  <h1 id="reg">Register here</h1>

 {{> add_info}} 
</body>


<template name="add_info">
<div id="d1">
<form> 
<label>You are</label><br>
  <select class="the_item11" id="ucat" required>
    <option></option>
    <option>DJ</option>
    <option>Singer</option>
    <option>Instrumentalist</option>
    <option>Band</option>   
  </select> <br>

  <label>Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="the_item1" id="uname" required><br>


  <label>Mobileno.</label><br>
  <input type="tel" class="the_item2" id="umobile" required><br>

    <label>EmailID</label><br>
  <input  class="the_item3" type="email" id="umail" required><br>
<br>    

    <input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [compound unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) index:

```
db.my_collection.ensureIndex(
    {
        email: 1,
        category: 1
    },
    {
        unique: 1
    }
)
```

Comment: where in the code should i place this..? & i have created a "meteor collection" while this seems for "mongo collection"

Answer (score 0):

Look at great package `meteor-autoform`

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform